# compare previous and present hash key values from a Pandas dataFrame

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I would like to compare the a previous and present dictionary keys values from a pandas DataFrame. I have something like this:

```
MyFrame= pd.DataFrame({"A":[6,4,7,10], "B":[8,10,90,100]})

for k,v in MyFrame.iteritems():

  for k1,v1 in MyFrame[k].iteritems():
        if MyFrame[k1+1]-MyFrame[k1]> 5: print("The threshold has been exceeded")
```

I would like to compare 4 with 6, 7 with 4 and so one from the column "A". Same with column "B". Any help will be appreciated

Comment: comparing 7 with 6 are not current and previous row value. To compare a series with itself shifted by a single row you call `shift` so you can replace your code with  `MyFrame['A'] != MyFrame['A'].shift()` or whatever

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you're attempting but you can compare the entire Series or df by calling `shift`:

```
In [169]:
MyFrame['A'].shift()

Out[169]:
0   NaN
1     6
2     4
3     7
Name: A, dtype: float64

In [168]:
MyFrame.shift()

Out[168]:
    A   B
0 NaN NaN
1   6   8
2   4  10
3   7  90
```

Comment: thank you. I have a condition like if previous-current !=5 , print("  the threshold has been exeeded")

Comment: Well I think you mean if the threshold is greater than 5, anyway this would do the same thing: `MyFrame - MyFrame > 5`

Comment: you are right it >5. but how do i index the current and previous values based on the key. In the second loop i use MyFrame[k].iteritems():. so how will i index key in that loop? MyFrame[k][k1]?

Comment: Why do you need to loop though? `MyFrame[MyFrame - MyFrame > 5]` will show you which values meet that criteria